# How to run Mstests on a Mac?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-2010, mono, automated-tests

I have a need to write some mstests and run these tests on a Mac. The binaries for the source code being tested are already up and running on Mac.

To run test automation written in Visual studio, do I follow the same process? Any pointers on how to get started with running these test cases **using Mono on a Mac**?

Comment: This sounds like you will end up with testing your environment rather than the actual product.

Comment: Since Mono doesnt support running MStests, i am basically looking for a way to run test automation on a Mac

Comment: You should use .NET Core (which supports unit testing with MSTest, NUnit and xUnit.net). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-mstest

Answer (score 2):

I know this issue is old but I came across it while searching for solutions for running MSTest on my mac. I'll investigate the above but also worth noting that MSTest support on VS 4 Mac is imminent:

> MSTest support in Visual Studio for Mac will be available in 15.5 release cycle aka VSfM 7.3, which is planned to hit Alpha channel in few weeks.
> (20th September 2017)

[See this github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest/issues/1115)

However - if you can't wait - you can use the `dotnet` cli command:

> dotnet test CreditCardValidator.iOS.MSTestAppium/CreditCardValidator.iOS.MSTestAppium.csproj
>
> Build started, please wait... Build completed.
>
> Test run for
> /Users/owenniblock/test-apps/CCExampleAppium/CreditCardValidator.iOS.MSTestAppium/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/CreditCardValidator.iOS.MSTestAppium.dll(.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0) Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version
>
> 15.3.0-preview-20170628-02 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Starting test execution, please wait... Failed
>
> CreditCardValidator.iOS.MSTestAppium.Tests.IntentionalFailure Error
> Message:  Assert.IsTrue failed.  Stack Trace:    at
> CreditCardValidator.iOS.MSTestAppium.Tests.IntentionalFailure() in
> /Users/owenniblock/test-apps/CCExampleAppium/CreditCardValidator.iOS.MSTestAppium/Tests.cs:line
> 21
>
> Total tests: 3. Passed: 2. Failed: 1. Skipped: 0. Test Run Failed.
>
> Test execution time: 1.0736 Seconds

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is now possible, but that you have to build the executable yourself (at this point in time):
https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx
https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx-docs/blob/master/docs/contribute.md#building-with-visual-studiovs

You should follow the "Building with Visual Studio" instructions, using VS for Mac, or Xamarin Studio.

UPDATE: I tried this myself with VS for Mac v.7.1.3 and did not have success. In theory, this is possible, however... As you can see it's on GitHub though, so you should be able to submit an issue there, if there isn't a suitable one.

Answer (score 0):

Likewise, I came across this issue when trying to implement MSTests on a project and I can confirm that VS 4 Mac v8.8 supports MSTest and they run fine.