# How to run MSTest unit tests on Mac from command line?

Tags: macos, unit-testing, xamarin, terminal, mstest

I am working on Visual Studio for Mac. 
I am using test project with

- MSTest.TestAdapter
- MSTest.TestFramework

The project target is .NET Framework 4.6.1
(I need .NET Framwork to use Xamarin.UITest)

I can run this test library in the IDE by right clicking the project and selecting "Run Item".

How can I run those tests via terminal on a Mac?

It's not working with:

```
dotnet test
```

because it is not .NET Core.

On windows there seems to be a MSTest.exe. I couldn't find it on the mac via the "which" command.

Is there a way to start this test on mono with an executable that runs the test adapter?
Like a mstest equivalent to nuint-console on a Mac.

**Edit:** The question: [How to run Mstests on a Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289117/how-to-run-mstests-on-a-mac) doesn't work for this problem because (see above) the tests aren't able to run under .NET Core. They are targeting the .NET Framework.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run Mstests on a Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289117/how-to-run-mstests-on-a-mac)

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, this is specifically using the CLI